# Batch file to recursively delete files in a folder older than N number of days

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, cmd

I'm using a batch file now to delete all files ending in `.snp` that are older than 180 days. The code below works to delete all files ending in `.snp` under the root folder

> C:\Program Files\Snapshots

But I recently discovered that within the Snapshots folder there are folders organized by date

> "1-10-2014, 12-20-2014, 10-15-2014 etc.."

and that the below line of code doesn't work to recursively search through each directory and is therefore not deleting.

What changes should I make to this code to have it recursively search through folders within a root folder and delete files that are greater than 180 days?

```
forfiles /M *.snp /P "C:\Program Files\Snapshots" /S /D -180 /C "cmd /c del /F /Q @path"
```

Comment: have you checked without del commands? `forfiles /M *.snp /P "C:\Program Files\Snapshots" /S /D -180 /C "cmd /c echo @path"`

Answer (score 4):

Without the /D (Date) it workes for sub-folders

```
forfiles /M *.txt /P "C:\hlpme" /S /C "cmd /c del /f /q @path
```

but you obviously want the date to be there
then in CMD

```
forfiles /D -180 /M *.txt /P "C:\hlpme" /S /C "cmd /c del /f /q @path
```

The /D before the Pathname selects all files that have been changed more than 180 days ago

Answer (score 1):

The best option for highest reliability is to combine the strengths of the For command with the FORFILES commands to allow each one to do what they do best.

```
Set str_Ext=*.snp
Set int_Age=-180
For /R "%~dp0" %%D IN (.) DO (
    For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%F IN (`FORFILES /P "%%~D" /m %str_Ext% /D %int_Age% 2^>nul`) DO (
        Call :s_Del_File "%%~D" "%%~F"
    )
)
Goto :EOF
:s_Del_File
Set "str_DIR=%~1"
Set "str_FIL=%~2"
Set "str_DIR=%str_DIR:~0,-1%"
DEL /F/Q/A "%str_DIR%%str_FIL%"
Goto :EOF
```

Within the second FOR command, the backquote (~ key) contains the FORFILES command and uses the console output to call a batch subroutine to delete the specified file.

Spaces in folder and file names will not slow this beast down, and the double quotes ["] around the Set commands will allow the process to work with folders and files that have parentheses in them or other exotic, but allowable characters.